# Undefined method type

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to shrink this Java code as much as possible:

```
Consumer consumerone = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
            byte[] body) throws IOException {
        processobjone(body);
    }
};
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_FIRST_NAME, true, consumerone);

Consumer consumersec = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
            byte[] body) throws IOException {
        processobjsec(body);
    }
};
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_SEC_NAME, true, consumersec);

// Processing

private void processobjone(byte[] body) {       
    // handle obj
}

private void processobjsec(byte[] body) {   
    // handle obj
}

// .... and many more
```

I tried this possible solution but I get multiple errors:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

Map<String, Consumer<byte[]>> queueToConsumer = new HashMap<>();
queueToConsumer.put(ElementTypeEnum.QUEUE_TRANSACTION, this::process_transaction);
queueToConsumer.put(ElementTypeEnum.QUEUE_API_ATTEMPT, this::process_api_attempt);

queueToConsumer.forEach((queueName, consumer) -> {
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, new DefaultConsumer() {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            consumer.accept(body);
        }
    });
});

private void process_transaction(byte[] vv) {       
}

private void process_api_attempt(byte[] vv) {       
}
```

These are the errors when I made the changes:

```
The method basicConsume(String, boolean, Consumer) in the type Channel is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean, new DefaultConsumer(){})
```

Can you advice how I can solve the issues? Probably I need to change the pattern which is used to redirect to proper Java methods?

Comment: Check the spec for creating a Consumer method along with the api of basicConsume

Comment: This is my own example. Spec is not related. Can you propose some solution?

Comment: I mostly improved the formatting of the code to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks but can you propose some solution for the problem?

Comment: can you try importing DefaultConsumer

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Eclipse misguide me about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like DefaultConsumer was not imported, causing the compiler to not recognise it